# Abrir PDF em uma nova aba do nagevador

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Implementei uma funcionalidade no sistema de gerar um arquivo PDF usando o iTextSharp, porém esta abrindo na mesma aba, gostaria que fosse aberto em uma nova aba do navegador. Tentei usar o `Response.Redirect
 Response.Write`
 
Tentei usar o `target = _blank`.  E diversas outras coisas que encontrei no Google, porém não tive sucesso em nenhum. Alguém poderia dar um help?

Minha função esta assim

```cs
Private Sub gerarPDF(ByVal texto As String, ByVal arquivo As String)

    Dim dTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim arquivoPDF = arquivo & dTime.Second & dTime.Millisecond & ".pdf"
    If (arquivo.Contains(".pdf")) Then
        arquivo = arquivo.Replace(".pdf", "")
    End If


    Dim doc As iTextSharp.text.Document = New iTextSharp.text.Document
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\" & arquivoPDF, FileMode.Create))

    Dim img = doc.Add(New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("JPG"))
    doc.Open()
    For Each E1 As iTextSharp.text.IElement In HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(texto), New StyleSheet())
        doc.Add(E1)
    Next
    doc.Close()
    Response.Redirect("~/" & arquivoPDF)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnImprimir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImprimir.Click
    gerarPDF(txtMensagemHistorico.Text, "HistoricoMsg_")
End Sub
```

Comment: Bom dia estou com a mesma duvida vc conseguiu resolver ?